# Mouse_entered on pieChart results in a onclick?

Tags: javafx, mouseevent

I am unable to get a mousehover property for JavaFX pieChart. Using the mouse_entered property result in a mouse_pressed instead. To get the program to print "blabla" I have to press each slide, instead of hovering it.

I use the following code:

```
for (PieChart.Data d : pieChartData) {
      ));
         d.getNode().addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED,
    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
           System.out.println("blabla");
         }
    });     
    }
```

Comment: This works as expected for me. Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You get the hovering effect? Or do you have to click to get it?

Comment: It prints the message as the mouse enters the node. No click is required.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/D8HRH4k7

Here is the controller in a bastebin.

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)